# How to find LSTMCell weight and bias names to load values into them?

Tags: tensorflow

I have been trying to load some altered weights back into the Tensorflow computational graph while training a multilayered LSTM RNN. Using the follwing lines of code:

```
variables_names =[v.name for v in tf.trainable_variables()]
values = session.run(variables_names)
```

gives me names and values of the variables used, the names of the weights of the LSTMCells however are in the form

```
rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/lstm_cell/weights:0
rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_1/lstm_cell/weights:0
```

and so on, but I cannot use the above names directly in

```
rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/lstm_cell/weights.load(values[0], session)
```

method to load the values back. Does anyone know how to load new weights back into the LSTM cells?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to turn a variable name into a `tf.Variable` object is to filter `tf.trainable_variables()`, matching on the name:

```
cell_0_weights = [v for v in tf.trainable_variables()
                  if v.name == 'rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/lstm_cell/weights:0'][0]
```

(This is not particularly efficient, but the set of variables is usually small enough that the inefficiency is unimportant.)

Once you have a `tf.Variable` object, you can use its [`load()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable#load) method to assign a new weight:

```
cell_0_weights.load(values[0], sess)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works! Also after filtering `tf.trainable_variables()` to get `cell_0_weights`, I tried using the load method for the variable and that works too. by using `cell_0_weights.load(values[0], session)`.

Comment: I forgot that method existed! Much nicer :).